# C# windows service: HTML page with picture, CSS and JS as a response

Tags: c#, html, css

I am learning to build a windows service, but it takes requests (e.g. localhost:8081/index) from the browser to. Therefore, the HTTP response should contain an HTML page. 
The HTML page looks okay when I double click the index.html file, but it lost all the CSS and js files when I request from the web browser. **And I open the developer's tool in chrome and found out that all the CSS and JS files were corrupted and contain the code from my HTML page (weird).**
[image: Screenshot from developer tool]

I used HttpListenerContext class to listen for http://localhost/index request, and then open index.html file and used File.ReadAllBytes(file). When composing the response, I used the following code:

```
responseBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
response.ContentLength64 = responseBytes.Length;
await response.OutputStream.WriteAsync(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length); 
response.OutputStream.Close();
```

Can anyone help me to figure out why this is happening?

Comment: You will either have to pack everything into your html or host your .css, .js, etc. elsewhere since you only write out html to your output. If you just refer to .css and .js files, how would your browser obtain those resources? Your HttpListenerContext receives the requests for those resources but just spits out the html.

Comment: I know what you mean, but there is a working example in my company's code base though. It doesn't seem like it's doing extra steps to load other resources than the HTML file

Comment: It's likely your `HttpListenerContext` is listening for any request made to that domain and serving the same content no matter what the path/filename. Without seeing more of your setup, it's impossible to say.

Comment: Hi Mike, the code structure is simple, first open the listener and wait for the request. Then based on the HttpMethod (e.g. GET ) , I read the Url and get the web content (e.g. index.html). Then I write the response and return. Is this what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the answer by myself when I traced the code. When request localhost/index comes in from the browser, the GET method will first acquire index.html first, then there are other GET requests come in for the CSS, image and JS as well (It's weird that I didn't see the later requests before.)

Then I updated the handler to compose responses contains CSS, image and JS files. Everything works perfectly now.